# Nested dictionary from dataframe with loop over list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, nested

complete newbie here.

I want to read data from two columns in several excel sheets in a nested dictionary. In the end, I'd like to have a dictionary looking like this:

```
{SheetName1:{Index1: Value1, Index2: Value2,...}, SheetName2:{Index1: Value1, Index2: Value2} ...}
```

So far I read in the data using pandas and figured out how to combine the two columns I need into the inner dictionary {Index: Value}, which afterwards gets assigned the name of the sheet as a key to from the outer dictionary:

```
#read excel sheet into dataframe
df = ExcelWorkbook.parse(sheet_name = None, header= 1, usecols= 16, skiprows= 6)

#read in the different excel sheet names in a List
    SHEETNAMES = []
    SHEETNAMES = ExcelWorkbook.sheet_names

#nested dictionary
for Sheet in SHEETNAMES:
    df[Sheet] = df[Sheet].loc[0:87,:]
    dic = dict(zip(df[Sheet].index, df[Sheet]['ColumnName']))
    dic = {Sheet: dic}
```

Now when I run this, it only returns the last sheet with its corresponding {Index: Value} pair:

```
{'LastSheetName': {Key1: Value1, Key2: Value2,...}
```

Now it seems to me that I've done the "harder" part but I can't seem to figure out, how to fill a new dictionary with the dictionaries generated by this loop....

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `dic` as a new variable each time you iterate through your for loop. Instead, instantiate `dic` as an empty list `[]` outside of the loop and then append the dictionaries you define inside the loop to it, such as:

```
#read excel sheet into dataframe
df = ExcelWorkbook.parse(sheet_name = None, header= 1, usecols= 16, skiprows= 6)

#nested dictionary
dic = []
for Sheet in ExcelWorkbook.sheet_names:
    df[Sheet] = df[Sheet].iloc[0:87,:]
    out = {Sheet: dict(zip(df[Sheet].index, df[Sheet]['ColumnName']))}
    dic.update(out)
```

Also, you want you to use `.iloc` in place of `.loc` considering you are specifying index locations inside of the dataframe.

Comment: Hey Rahlf23,

first of all: thank you very much for your help!
The solution you posted works, but not a 100% as intended:

Now I got a List of dictionaries as you mentioned: [{...}, {....}...] but I'd like to use the sheet names to adress the values within the dictionary. E.g:
`print(dic[SheetName1][Index1]) = xxx`
Which I think is not possible with a list?

So I am looking for something like 
`{SheetName1:{Index1: Value1}....}` 
rather than `[SheetName1:{Index1: Value1]`

Do you have any further ideas?
Best regards,
Jan

Comment: You bet, thank you for clarifying your question. I have updated my answer to reflect your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out after tweaking @rahlf23 response a bit. So for anyone looking this up:

dic.append() does not work for dictionaries, instead I used dic.update():

```
#nested dictionary
dic1 = {}
for Sheet in SHEETNAMES:
    df[Sheet] = df[Sheet].iloc[0:87,:]
    out = dict(zip(df[Sheet].index, df[Sheet]['ColumnName']))
    out2 = {Sheet: out}
    dic1.update(out2)
```

Now one can access the values with:

```
print(dic1[SheetName][Index])
```

Thanks for your help @rahlf23, without your comment I'd still be trapped in the loop :)